# Dealing with return undefined with typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that has typechecking on it for type `Promise<void>`. However, the way my function works, I want it to return undefined if a condition is false, and return data that is `Promise<void>` type if it's true. How do I avoid a type error for the scenario where the function returns undefined without losing the type-checking on the other scenario? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to return "data" as `Promise<void>`. That means you're awaiting data that is `void` type.

Comment: I'd also discourage the use of conditional promise types. Make the resolved data type conditional rather than the promise itself (e.g. `Promise<A | B>` rather than `A | Promise<B>`)

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question though? As it stands, it seems like there's missing information. A simplified example of what you're trying to achieve (and what the issue is) would go a long way here.

Comment: Given the described logic, `Promise<T | undefined>` sounds most appropriate given how one would naturally consume it.